FHI-aims basis sets only up tp Z=102?
I would need fhi-aims supporting elements up to Z=120.
Looking into the directory fhi-aims.240507/species_defaults I see support only up to Z=102.
There is, however, the fhi-aims.240507/species_defaults/non-standard/STOs directory, which has 'Z's up to 118. For instance, the fhi-aims.240507/species_defaults/non-standard/STOs/TZP_ae/118_Og_default is just copy of Z=102.
The question is if there is a quick, viable vay to construct missing FHI--aims basis sets up to Z=120.

The spin-orbit splitting of the 7p orbital is 10 eV already for Og [doi:10.1002/anie.201908327], which means that variational inclusion of the spin-orbit effects i.e. full four-component calculations is extremely important for the superheavy elements. I guess FHI-aims can now be quasi-4c calculations...
